# HTML errors when truncating?

Tags: php, html

I have the following function:

```
function truncate($string, $limit, $break=".", $pad="...") { 
  if(strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string; 
    if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit))) { 
      if($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1) { 
        $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad; 
      } 
    } 

    return $string; 
}
```

If i have the following code:

```
$html = '<div style="bla: bla;">somet30ext</div> <div id="bla">MORE AND MORE TEXT</div>';
print truncate($html, 30);
```

It will cut off at somet..... In other words, we end with:

```
<div style="bla: bla;">somet
```

I.e. an unclosed div tag. How do I go about solving this?

Update:

I don't want to truncate only when I get to the . I want something that can automatically add divs. In this case, the output should be:

```
     <div style="bla: bla;">somet</div>
```

I.e. It actually added the  because it knew it was unclosed? Am I correct in assuming I must use something like html purifier for this?

Comment: Are counting the tags and attributes and attributes values as well for the truncation count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't truncate the `$html` but rather the *real text* where it's appropriate. To get hold of the text, you could use php's xml functions ([DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/book.dom.php), [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/book.simplexml.php)) or regular expression. Though I'd advice the first.

Example using Dom:

```
$html = '<div style="bla: bla;">somet30ext</div> <div id="bla">MORE AND MORE TEXT</div>';

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

// example of getting a div with id=bla
$bla = $xpath->query('//div[@id="bla"]')->item(0);
if ($bla instanceof DomNode) {

  // truncate here
  if (strlen($bla->nodeValue) > 10) {
    $bla->nodeValue = substr($bla->nodeValue, 0, 10) . '...';
  }
}

// collect result, this is needed due to dom->loadhtml wrapping the loaded string
// with html/body if not present
$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->query('//body/*') as $childNode) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Ok, so now I need a function that strips the tags, truncates it, and then re-adds the relevant html tags?

Comment: No, you'll use one of the given libraries to find the text *inside* the html and truncate it there. This way the html-structure will remain untouched. I'll try to provide an example shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in truncate function just look for opening tags, count them, and look for these tags to close, when all are closed that's is your string.

Comment: so you want to add html tag to the end ?

Comment: Or: Close them if they are still open at the end of truncation.

Comment: Ok, you cut html code, when it's not closed, so that's why you need to keep a list of open tags, so that if you're truncated your text before tag is closed, you need to add that tag to string.
But basically, this is not very good approach, to cut text with html.
I would suggest, having new variable, which holds only text, check the place where it will be cut in variable with html, and only then cut the string with html.

Comment: How would I then add the html again afterwards at the right locations?!

Comment: your truncate on html items would work like comments, so when you know actual string length to cut, just make sure truncate ignores html tags (use regexp).