# php substr in html dom

Tags: php, regex, substr

How can I use `substr()` in a HTML dom? I want keep all the html tags and just shorten the text.

```
$str = '<div><a href="http://www.weather.com">Today is a nice day</a></div>';
$part1 = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i",substr('\\2', 0,10),$str).'...';
$part2 = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i",'\\2',$str);
echo str_replace($part2,$part1,$str);// nothing change
// I need <div><a href="http://www.weather.com">Today is a...</a></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML errors when truncating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159695/html-errors-when-truncating)

Comment: @Yoshi: not really a duplicate

Comment: @rabudde How is it not a duplicate? It deals with truncating text-nodes without corrupting the html-structure?

Comment: it should put `substr` after `preg_replace`. `$str = '<div><a href="http://www.weather.com">Today is a nice day</a></div>';
$part1 = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i",'${2}',$str);
$part1 = substr($part1, 0,10).'...';
$part2 = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i",'${2}',$str);
echo str_replace($part2,$part1,$str);`

Comment: @Yoshi: he wants to truncate text in all nodes, that "duplicate" wants to correct only broken HTML syntax after truncating a specific number of chars.

Comment: @rabudde the accepted answer provides an example of how to truncate text nodes without breaking the structure in the first place. This can easily be adapted to more than a specific node (e.g. *all nodes*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could probably be a bit more robust, but this should do the trick:

```
$str = '<div><a href="http://www.weather.com">Today is a nice day</a></div>';
echo shortenLinks($str);

function shorten($matches) {
   $maxlen = 10;
   $str = $matches[2];
   if (strlen($str) > $maxlen) {
      return "<" . $matches[1] . ">" . substr($str, 0, $maxlen) . "...<";
   } else {
      return $matches[0];
   }
}

function shortenLinks($str) {
   $pattern = "/<(a\s+.*)>([^<]+)</";
   return preg_replace_callback($pattern, "shorten", $str);
}
```

Comment: @answered, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in line `$callback = function($matches) {`

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: thanks, but why I can not use simple `substr()` in `preg_replace`?

Comment: Ok, I figue out the problem, put `substr` after the preg_replace, it could work.